# 1bpp Monochromatic BMP

Tags: c++, bitmap, bmp

I ran a demo bmp file format helper program "DDDemo.exe" to help me visualize the format of a 32x1 pixel bmp file (monochromatic). I'm okay with the the two header sections but dont seem to understand the color table and pixel bits portions. I made two 32x1 pixel bmp files to help me compare (please see attached).

[image: one black then one white pixel etc]

[image: 16 black pixels then 16 white pixels]

Can someone assit me understand how the "pixel bits" relates to the color map?

UPDATE: After some trial and error I finally was able to write a 32x1 pixel monochromatic BMP. Although it has different pixel bits as the attached images, this tool helped with the header and color mapping concept. Thank you for everyones input.

Comment: The bitmaps have ClrUsed = 0, even though they have a color table with 2 entries.  Enough to confuse the stuffing out of that program, I guess.

Comment: `0` is a perfectly valid value for [`biClrUsed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapinfoheader): *"If `biClrUsed` is zero, the array contains the maximum number of colors for the given bitdepth; that is, 2^`biBitCount` colors"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An unset bit in the PIXEL BITS refers to the first color table entry (0,0,0), black, and a set bit refers to the second color table entry (ff,ff,ff), white.

"The 1-bit per pixel (1bpp) format supports 2 distinct colors, (for example: black and white, or yellow and pink). The pixel values are stored in each bit, with the first (left-most) pixel in the most-significant bit of the first byte. Each bit is an index into a table of 2 colors. This Color Table is in 32bpp 8.8.8.0.8 RGBAX format. An unset bit will refer to the first color table entry, and a set bit will refer to the last (second) color table entry." - [BMP file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Pixel_Array_.28bitmap_data.29)

Comment: I think the OP is asking how what you wrote correlates to the data in "PIXEL BITS".

Comment: It's hard to know without understanding what his viewer is doing to the data.

Answer (score 2):

The color table for these images is simply indicating that there are two colors in the image:

- Color 0 is `(00, 00, 00)` -- pure black
- Color 1 is `(FF, FF, FF)` -- pure white

The image compression method shown (`BI_RGB` -- uncompressed) doesn't make sense with the given pixel data and images, though.

Comment: There are 32 pixel bits, so the number seems right for uncompressed bi_rgb. But where's AB 01 08 00 coming from?

Comment: That's what I don't get. `AB 01 08 00` looks like some sort of compressed data, which doesn't jive with the compression method. If it really were uncompressed, I'd expect something like `00 00 FF FF`.